# Passing a list of instances of object to the method from another class

Tags: python-3.x, object, instance

I am trying to pass a list of instances of objects in the class of another object. When I am doing this directly - that everything is working as it should. When they pass the list is wrapped in a tuple, it does not work.
Сomparing the outputs:

for **report**:

> Record: None, None, None
>
> Record: E001, IPTV and telematics, at Nov 20: everything is sad
>
> Record: E002, DPI, None

for **report1**:

> None
>
> (<**main**.Record object at 0x7f7b88d65908>, <**main**.Record object at 0x7f7b88d65940>, <**main**.Record object at 0x7f7b88d65978>)
>
> None

***How that possible? And how to fix it?***

```
class Ticket:
  tickets = []
  def __init__(self, id=None, group=None):
    self.id = id
    self.group = group
    self.tickets.append(self)

class Record(Ticket):  
  records = []
  def __init__(self, ticket=None, comment=None):
    self.ticket = ticket
    self.comment = comment
    self.records.append(self)

  def __str__(self):
    if self.ticket != None:
      return 'Record: ' +  '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(self.ticket.id, self.ticket.group, self.comment)

class Report:  
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.records = list(args)

  def show_all(self):
    for record in self.records:
      print(record)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  t1 = Ticket('E001', 'IPTV and telematics')
  t2 = Ticket('E002', 'DPI')
  rec1 = Record(Ticket())
  rec2 = Record(t1, 'at Nov 20: everything is sad')
  rec3 = Record(t2)

  report = Report(rec1,rec2,rec3)
  print(report.show_all())

  report1 = Report(tuple(rec1.records))
  print(report1.show_all())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you're passing the Record instances as separate parameters. In this case, `args` will be a tuple containing the 3 arguments.

In the second case, you're passing a single parameter, a tuple. As in the first case, `args` will be a tuple containing the arguments given: a tuple containing the Record instances.

If you need to pass a list (or a tuple) with the intention that each list item should be interpreted as a separate argument, [use `*` to unpack the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
report1 = Report(*rec1.records)
```